# Weird behaviour of logical mosfet in proteus

Tags: mosfet, driver

I'm trying to drive a P-Mosfet logical from a 2-3Decoder 74HC238, the problem is whatever the Input to the MOSFET's gate, I always get a high output on the drain.

Kindly find the attached schematic, if there is a faulty mistake. [image]

Q1 is the output,  DEM1 is the input from the 74HC238 ( directly connected )

Comment: No, you have the drain tied to ground. Perhaps you meant to use an N-channel MOSFET in this circuit.

Comment: BTW, if you expect others to read your circuit diagrams, put the inputs on the left, the outputs on the right and the positive supply at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your circuit was intended to be like the following and you have connected the Source-Drain inverted (and a P type instead on N type).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMLwfT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Proteus simulation, showing both states

[image]

---

Proteus simulation, showing both states using 74HC238 to drive the gate

[image]

Comment: I tried your setup with the 2N7000 in the simulator proteus, still it didn't work. That's really weird.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Works fine for me, please see edit

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the 74HC238 output? is there something that should I take care of ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh That works fine too, please see latest edit

Comment: Thanks so much. The thing is I'm gonna drive a 7-segment out of this, so I would like to have a positive output based on a positive input from the 74HC238, so I would better use a P-MOSFET ? Heck! I was an EE, but I forgot it 7 years ago :(. Would you also suggest a P-MOSFET that can be simulated in proteus correctly ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Using a P-mosfet with the output taken from the drain will have the same inversion problem [simulation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rX4k7.jpg). The alternative of moving the 360R resistor to the source side will cause problems, as soon as current starts flowing through it the source pin voltage will get higher,  reducing Vgs. If you are looking for a one component solution maybe you should consider a NPN used as an emitter follower [schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OydpQ.jpg).

Comment: its ashamed on me that I forgot that I'm using currently a MOSFET as an inverter. I forgot everything. I would try the NPN Solution, but I would like a high current darlington pair for more than 5A, have a suggestion ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh You need an inverter, either a second transistor or a second mosfet. Another solution is to use logic gate inverters between the 74HC238 and the mosfet gate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the right components in the wrong places. Try one of these.

Implementation with a P-channel FET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzHeKJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Keeping the P-channel FET, a logic low input will result in the FET conducting, current through R1, and a logic high at the output.

Implementation with an N-channel FET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fII2M9.png)</sup>

Replacing with an N-channel FET, a logic low input will result in the FET not conducting, no current through R1, and a logic high at the output.

Both schematics assume your supply voltage, Vcc, is equivalent to your input voltage. If all you have is a P-channel FET, go with the first schematic. However, N-channel FETs are usually cheaper than a P-channel with similar capability. It also depends when you want a voltage across R1 as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a problem with the proteus, it still didn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried isolating the issue at all? For instance, if you configure your circuit as @alexan_e has, will it work? If it does, then maybe something is wrong with your input. If it doesn't, then it must be a component or simulation issue.